# Fifteen close votes on one question in low-quality queue

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, review, low-quality-posts

For this particular review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3437631

The question got fifteen close votes over the course of an hour.  Seems like that's a lot.

This could indicate a bug.

Comment: They don't have 3k rep... Can people with less even VTC questions in the low quality queue?

Comment: There were only *five* close votes. The rest were all flags that got misrecorded.

Comment: The help vampires would kill for this feature: The ability to ask a question that takes 15 close votes to close. :P:P:P