# Over a dozen close recommendations are needed?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

This review https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3542856 seems to need at least a dozen close recommendations:

[image]

Comment: Recommend Close just adds the post to the Close Review queue *as well*.

Comment: On the plus side, this bug does illustrate the consistency and consensus of the twelve SO reviewers on this particular question.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208928/fifteen-close-votes-on-one-question-in-low-quality-queue and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208221/low-quality-review-queue-erroneously-showing-close-instead-of-recommended-clo

Comment: Agreed, you found better targets.

Comment: @Shog9: Maybe, as per your suggestion of [Nov 8th](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204743/147362), someone should make a feature-request: "I do think it probably makes sense to just skip over heavily-flagged posts for reviewers unable to actually vote though. And this might even be feasible to implement."

Comment: @Shog9 - how is this *not* a bug?  Per my duplicate (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208221/low-quality-review-queue-erroneously-showing-close-instead-of-recommended-clo), it used to show `Recommend Close` when users with <3000 rep voted, but now they all say `Close`.  I haven't seen this annoucned anywhere that the wording had changed, and it's extremely confusing to users already familiar with the system.

Comment: *That* is a bug, @LBT - the fact that over a dozen of them were collected isn't though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All but 4 of those reviewers have less than 3k reputation, and can only *recommend* closure. Their votes added this post to the Close Review queue as well.

A fifth voter, perhaps from the Close Review queue cast the 5th actual close vote; see the [now-closed question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476016/create-a-websql-database-from-a-form-selection-via-radial-buttons-and-submit):

> put on hold as too broad by Nathaniel Ford, legoscia, bensiu, mehow, Chris Laplante 21 mins ago

where Nathaniel, legoscia, bensiu and mehow all are recorded as having voted to close in the low-quality review queue, in the same order that they are listed in the 'on hold' notice.