# Let me get the "review completed" box out of the way

Tags: feature-request, review, design

[A very interesting review task was brought up in the Tavern overnight.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1902693#1902693) The primary interesting factor here is it took 45(!) review actions to complete the review, where the usual thresholds are a Looks Good, an Edit, or 6 Recommend Deletions. That's not what I'm here to complain about. What I'm here to complain about is my Surface's screen is only high enough to see 34 of them, and my normal laptop's screen fits all of them but only leaves about 84px for the post. Which is fine, except that there's no way short of dev tools to get them out of the way.

> [image: There's something to review here... if only I could see it...]

It would be highly appreciated if that floating box had some sort of "let me see the darn thing" switch.

Comment: Well is there a real request in there? A list of reviews is not meant to actually be that long, so why would we need a feature to account for it?

Comment: 43 delete recommendations and not a single close vote

Comment: @animuson The real request is in the second-last paragraph, just below the image. And yes, it's an edge case, but it's an *annoying* edge case.

Comment: Incidently my phone can cope with this fine (Samsung galaxy S3 - android)

Comment: @michaelb958 But a feature that only applies to an edge-case that occurs once in 4,000,000 reviews is not useful. If you think it would be useful under *normal* circumstances, then you should say that. Otherwise it's a bit of a pointless request. It'd be better to prevent a bug from appearing than to make a bug look pretty.

Comment: @animuson Eh, [[meta-tag:status-declined]] happens to everyone eventually.

Comment: @RichardTingle it's not possible (and quite pointless) to close an answer. Close votes can be cast only on questions. :)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Over a dozen close recommendations are needed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210821)

Comment: @JosephQuinsey No, this is quite different as close recommendations are just flags, for recommend deletion "votes", when you get 6 it's auto-deleted.

Comment: This is pretty hard to navigate from Chrome on a large laptop.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Qantas was encouraged to post about the insane number of recommendations, not about the resulting display issue. Also, I left the bug/request-ness indeterminate; animuson decided it was more a request, and I'm not inclined to disagree.

Comment: @animuson shouldn't this be very easy to complete, though? Just add a `max-height` and `overflow:auto`?

Comment: "my Surface's screen..." MS dork alert. Surfaces stink. I mean, from a user experience standpoint they can be considered "user hostile".

Comment: @bjb568 I'm sorry. I don't particularly adore it either.

Comment: @Sha Ah I see, now that the answer is deleted it looks like its a question review

Comment: @Richard questions will not appear in low quality review, but yeah can see what you mean. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Of course questions appear in the low quality queue. There was a bug for quite a while that stopped them turning up except in corner cases, but that was fixed ages ago.

Comment: @michael oh, guess I was checking during the bug then but anyhow there's no "Recommend Deletion" for questions in there, right? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, just "Recommend Close" (or "Close").